# Duality and compactness for pro vector spaces

Tags: limits-and-colimits, topological-vector-spaces, condensed-mathematics

I have a somewhat basic question which I haven't been able to piece together from the literature.

**Background.** We work over a field $\bf{k}$. Consider the category,  $\bf{Pro}_{k}$, of pro- vector spaces over $k$. This contains two full subcategories which are dual to one another. Namely the category $\bf{Mod}_{k}$ of $\bf{k}$ vector spaces, and the category $\bf{Profin}_{k}$ of profinite vector spaces.That these are dual follows from the equivalence $$\operatorname{Ind}(\bf{Mod}_{k}^{fin})\cong\bf{Mod}_{k}.$$ and the usual ind-pro duality, coupled with the duality of finite dimensional vector spaces.

**Question 1.** Is the category $\bf{Pro}_{k}$ self dual? More specifically, is the functor $$*:\bf{Pro}\rightarrow\bf{Pro}^{op}$$ defined by $$V\mapsto V^{*}:=\operatorname{colim}^{\bf{Pro}}V_{i}^{*}$$ an equivalence? Here $V$ is a pro object $\{V_{i}\}_{i\in I}$, each $V_{i}^{*}$ is the corresponding profinite object, and $\operatorname{colim}^{\bf{Pro}}$ denotes the filtered colimit taken inside all pro vector spaces. As I recall it is a fact that such a filtered colimit exists. Unfortunately they seem hard to describe, which is the source of a lot of my problems.

**Question 2.** If the above is true it follows that profinite objects are compact and generate, as they are dual to usual vector spaces. Further, if profinite objects are compact and generate, then $\bf{Pro}$ would be $\operatorname{IndPro}(\bf{Mod}^{fin})$, which is obviously dual to $\operatorname{ProInd}(\bf{Mod}^{fin})=\bf{Pro}$, and so question 1 will admit a positive answer. Assuming it is *not* the case that **1** has a positive answer, is it at least still the case that elements of $\bf{Profin}$ are compact?

Comment: In any additive category with infinite products and coproducts we can consider the natural map $\bigoplus_i V_i \to \prod_i V_i$ from the infinite coproduct to the infinite product. I think it is plausible that if $A$ is an abelian category then this natural map is a monomorphism but usually not an epimorphism in $\text{Ind}(A)$, but the reverse in $\text{Pro}(A)$. I don't know how to prove that, but if that were true it would imply that the answer is no.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Of course, you are right.  For an abelian category $A$, the categories $\operatorname{Ind}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Pro}(A)$ are abelian with products and coproducts.  In an abelian category with products and coproducts, the natural map $\coprod_i X_i\rightarrow\prod_i X_i$ is always a monomorphism if and only if directed colimits are exact, or equivalently, directed colimits of monomorphisms are monomorphisms.

Comment: In the abelian category $\operatorname{Ind}(A)$, directed colimits of monomorphisms are monomorphisms (e.g., because $\operatorname{Ind}(A)$ can be defined as the full subcategory in the functor category $\operatorname{Fun_{add}}(A^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Ab})$ consisting of directed colimits of representable functors, and directed colimits of monomorphisms are monomorphisms in the functor category).

Comment: Dually, in the abelian category $\operatorname{Pro}(A)$, directed limits of epimorphisms are epimorphisms, so the natural map $\coprod_i X_i\rightarrow\prod_i X_i$ is always an epimorphism.  Finally, it is well known that the natural map $\coprod_i X_i\rightarrow\prod_i X_i$ cannot be always an isomorphism (e.g., when all the objects $X_i$ are the same and the set of indices is infinite), unless your category is zero.

Comment: This is nice, thanks to Qiaochu for the idea and to Leonid for the further explanation! As Leonid explains, k[x]-->k[[x]] is an epi, which maps to itself under the duality functor, but which is not a mono. Here k[x] is discrete and k[[x]] has the obvious pro structure.